# HP Virtual Connect and VLAN Tagging

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

We have a c7000 chasis with the ability to have 8 uplinks per ESX host. Only 6 are currenlty active.

I have a Virtual Switch with multiple vlan port groups and all the VMs are working fine.

Recently we've been asked to setup network load balancing for one of our VMs, so we had our Virtual Connect engineer
activate the last two uplinks. We then created a new vSwitch and added the two new uplinks to this vSwitch. We then moved the VM
to this new vSwitch, but we get no connectivity. What could be the issue? We also added the appropriate VLAN ID.

The VConnect engineer says everything is configured correctly and networking TEAM says the appropriate trunking is setup, so we are at a loss...

Comment: You never came back to me??

Comment: Welcome to Virtual Connect + ESX world...

Answer (score 1):

This is *right* up my street but I'm going to need a lot more information please, can you let me know the following;

1. your physical network layout including trunks and vlans carried by those trunks.
2. your VC networks and server profile for an example blade
3. your ESX network layout including vlan information
4. an example VM config including vnic and IP information

Thanks.